# Is it possible to reduce the range of the significand for FP numbers in Z3?

Tags: floating-point, z3

I am trying to run Z3 (C++) on a test case with a large number of floating point operations and it takes a long time to complete or hangs. To reduce the verification time, is it possible to force the LS bits of the significand (say the lower 12 bits) to 0 in FPA sort? The reduced range and precision for the significand is OK for my verification.
Or would it be better to define a new sort with fewer bits for the significand?
Are there any Z3 tactics I can use to speed up the FP verification?

For the properties I am trying to verify, the exact FP values are not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTLib (and z3) support floats with arbitrary exponent/significand sizes. See: https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-FloatingPoint.shtml

So, I'd recommend using the minimum exponent/significand size you can get away with, without affecting the semantics you want to use.

Forcing lower bits of the significand to be 0 might work, but I'd hazard a guess that it'd create a whole lot of extra assumptions you'd have to write, and it'd be a nightmare to manage those.

Regarding speeding up FP: Reducing bit-sizes is the best thing you can do. The FP theory pretty much bit-blasts the properties and turns them into SAT, so the fewer the bits, the better.